# ExpressionEngine over SSL - HTACCESS ISSUE

Tags: htaccess, ssl

I have a problem with my EE installation. When I try to browse any page (other than the homepage) over SSL i get a 404 error. The whole site works fine over HTTP. Its only when accessing via HTTPS this issue occurs.

My HTACCESS file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Removes index.php
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
# If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing
# make it /index.php?/$1 above (add the question mark)
</IfModule>
```

I've tried adding the ? in as per the comment on the last couple of rows, but to no avail.

I think the problem is my HTACCESS file, in particular the section that removes the index.php from the URL. If i add the index.php back into the URL then all my pages do work again under SSL.

For example:

```
https://mysite.com/store/checkout **does not work**
https://mysite.com/index.php?/store/checkout **DOES work**
```

I'm not enough of an htaccess expert to know how to resolve this. Any advise much appreciated.

Comment: This issue does not occur if you browser the site without https?

Comment: Exactly right. Viewing the site via http everything works fine. The issue is solely caused by https. (Editting my question to clarify that point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having gone round in circles for the best part of a day the issue was caused by a painfully simple issue.

My .httaccess file was in the wrong place. Following best practice advise I have moved my system folder above the web root and have the .htaccess file at that level.

Instead **the .htaccess file should have been placed in the web root**. As soon as I moved it there everything worked as expected.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
config
content <- web root
    *THIS IS where the htaccess file should be*
system
templates
*this is NOT where the htaccess file should be*
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this: http://kevinthompson.info/blog/2011/03/04/completely-remove-index-php-from-expressionengine-urls.html

I just recently discovered that solution and it's working great on our ecommerce website running with CartThrob and certain pages with https.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I did give that a go (its a nice solution Kevin has put together). Unfortunately the issue was down to user (me) stupidity rather than any specific code error.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `$config['uri_protocol']` setting in `config.php`, as I suggested in [this thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5470/150):

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

In that thread there are also a few other suggestions to try for the rewrite line:

- `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`
- `RewriteRule . index.php [L]`

Some combination of those two settings usually fixes things.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I did try that having found your thread in my searches. Unfortunately the issue was down to user stupidity rather than a server config error. Thanks for taking the time to respond.